# How to prevent putty / VIM bell on greater than character

Tags: vim, putty

I'm ussing Putty to connect via SSH and running VIM.  Whenever I enter a greater than character '>' the bell sound rings.

I can disable the bell entirely in Putty but that's not ideal.

Can anyone suggest why the bell rings when entering this character and how to make it stop?

Comment: hu... what? That the bell rings when typing the '>' in insert mode?? does it happen only with the '>' character?

Comment: The bell rings whenever the > character is typed in insert mode.  Presumably there are other times that the bell rings in VIM although I can't think of what they are right now.  But if I type something like this:

<html><head>

the bell would ring twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to disable the bell in **VIM**

---

PuTTY is responding to a terminal bell signal sent from VIM. To disable it type the following while in VIM **normal** (not insert) mode (hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> several times to make sure).

`:set vb t_vb=`

This will disable the audible and visual bell entirely for VIM.

You can add it to ~/.vimrc to make it permanent.

Comment: But VIM normally beeps when you've press some incorrect key, or when wants to call to attention to something. The OP seems to get a beep for an unexpected scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I was just fighting with this problem myself. According to a [thread I found on nabble](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/disable-visual-bell-in-insert-mode-for-PHP-file-td1157088.html), the beep is caused by showmatch being on and vim trying to find and jump to the opening `<` for the `>` you're typing.

This can either be fixed by setting [noshowmatch](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'showmatch'), or adjusting [matchpairs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'matchpairs') so that it doesn't match `<` and `>`

Answer (score 1):

Command for `>` in VIM:

`>` : Shift right (indent)

Comment: Yes, and if this happened in visual mode then maybe it would be because I couldn't indent or something like that.  But this happens on insert mode.